What will the pressure of accelerated air be relative to the pressure that accelerated it?
Imagine you have a high pressure reservoir filled with air. This reservoir is 1 psi
above ambient atmospheric pressure. There is also a valve attached to the reservoir.
Now, open this valve. The air will rush and accelerate out, and due to Bernoulli's principle, this fast air will be low-pressure.
Relative to the atmospheric pressure, what will the pressure of the accelerated air be at its maximum velocity? Will the low-pressure-peak be 1 psi below ambient? 0.5 psi?

This applies to aviation when the air travels to the front of an airfoil, accelerates over the top and becomes low pressure. I'm wondering the ratio between the pressure that accelerated the air over the foil vs. the pressure of the accelerated air itself.
I used the analogy of the pressure reservoir because I couldn't find a way to elegantly explain it using an airfoil, but the same principle still applies.

If there is anything that I missed, please comment and I will happily edit it in (or out)!

This belongs more to physics than aviation

Did we learn from jets that max velocity is at ambient pressure?  Certainly not less (that would slow the flow) (air rushing out of a high pressure container will have higher than ambient pressure)

Don't send aerodynamics questions over to Physics, it'll never get answered properly.

@RobMcDonald I actually had asked this on Physics.SE, and it never got an answer after multiple days, so I asked it here.

@RobMcDonald: for how much I like this kind of question and your perfect answer sorry but this whole story has nothing to do with airplanes. Otherwise I could ask any question about bikes because they have wheels just like airplanes...

Let's call the valve a nozzle.
In the reservoir, we have:
$P=P_{res}=P_{amb}+1\, \mathrm{psi}$
$V=V_{res}=0$
$\rho=\rho_{res}=\frac{P_{res}}{R\,T_{res}}$
The temperature is unspecified
$T=T_{res}$
If we assume a non-insulated reservoir that has been sitting for long time, then we can assume $T_{res}=T_{amb}$.
Next, let us assume that the nozzle is large enough that we can ignore viscous effects.  Let us also assume the pressure difference (1 psi) is small enough that we don't get into substantial compressible effects.
With these assumptions, Bernoulli's equation is all we need.  First, calculate the total pressure (stagnation pressure) inside the reservoir...
$P_0=P+0.5\,\rho\,V^2$
$P_{0,res}=P_{res}+0.5\,\rho_{res}\,(0)^2$
I.e. the total pressure is the pressure -- precisely because the flow is stagnant.
$P_{0,res}=P_{res}$
This flow will pass through the orifice without viscous effects, work addition (or removal), passing through shocks, etc.  We're also assuming incompressible for now.
These conditions are sufficient for the stagnation pressure to be a constant.  When the flow expands outside the reservoir, it will have the exact same total pressure.  However, it will expand to match the ambient pressure $P=P_{amb}$.  Since it is incompressible, the density will be constant.
Total pressure is constant
$P_{0,jet}=P_{0,res}=P_{res}$
Jet expands to ambient pressure
$P_{jet}=P_{amb}$
Jet is incompressible
$\rho_{jet}=\rho_{res}$
Write Bernoulli's equation for the jet...
$P_{0,jet}=P_{jet}+0.5\,\rho_{jet}\,{V_{jet}}^2$
Solve for $V_{jet}$
$V_{jet}=\sqrt{ \frac{P_{0,jet}-P_{jet}}{0.5\,\rho_{jet}}  }$
Because total pressure is constant and the jet expands to ambient pressure, we know the pressure difference in the numerator of the radical is 1 psi.
$V_{jet}=\sqrt{ \frac{1\,\mathrm{psi}}{0.5\,\rho_{jet}}}$
Substituting a few things we know
$V_{jet}=\sqrt{\frac{2\times 1\,\mathrm{psi}\,R\,T_{amb}}{P_{amb}+1\,\mathrm{psi}}}$
And converting psi to psf (pounds per square foot) because our density will be in slugs per cubic foot and Temperature in Rankine, etc.
$V_{jet}=\sqrt{\frac{288\,\mathrm{psf}\,R\,T_{amb}}{P_{amb}+144\,\mathrm{psf}}}$
Standard conditions.
$P_{amb}=2116.22 psf$
$T_{amb}=518.67 deg\, R$
$R=1716.46 ft\ lbf / (slug\ deg\,R)$
Doing the math
$V_{jet}=336.8 \,ft/sec$
Which is pretty reasonably for it still being incompressible.
A higher pressure ratio would violate incompressibility and you would not be able to use Bernoulli's equation.  Instead, in that case, you would want to use the Isentropic Flow Relations.  These are a set of equations that apply in a similar way, but that work for compressible flow.
Importantly, the isentropic flow relations calculate the ratio of total or stagnation properties to the ambient properties dependent on the Mach number.
Since you are starting from a reservoir, you would use the fact that velocity and Mach are zero in the reservoir and assign the reservoir properties as the total or stagnation properties.
Then, you can use the isentropic flow relations to expand the flow out to ambient.  We start with the assumption that the flow is perfectly expanded.  In that case, we use the Pressure equation of the isentropic flow relations to find the Mach number in the jet.
I'm pretty sure that if that Mach number is subsonic, then we're done.
If that Mach number is supersonic, then we need to understand the geometry of the nozzle more -- specifically, we need to know the area of the throat and the area of the exit.
We then treat it as a converging-diverging nozzle, with choked flow at the throat and expand the flow out to either an under-expanded or over-expanded condition at the nozzle exit.
I might have some details around how we determine if the nozzle flow is subsonic or supersonic, but you get the general idea.

Thanks for the very detailed answer! So where it says P= T= R=, are those the values required to get the psi (or psf)? If my inference is correct, 336.8 ft/s is the velocity that the air will be leaving the reservoir (or nozzle) at.

yes, if you plug in the three values (P,T,R) listed under standard conditions into the equation for Vjet above, you get the value of 336.8 ft/s given.  I will modify my answer to clarify those values a bit.

I see, thanks. So lastly, is there a way to convert 336 ft/s to the actual pressure of the accelerated stream? (Like 0.5 psi, or psf if it’s easier of the atmosphere pressure?) Sorry if you’ve already answered this, and I’ve not followed.

The pressure in the stream is ambient pressure.  The pressure is higher in the reservoir, it expands to ambient.

Very good and informative answer but... where's the airplane??

As I've pointed out before, there is no Aerospace Engineering forum on SE, so this one ends up fielding many aerodynamics questions.  You can't have a more fundamental aerodynamics question than an elementary homework problem applying Bernoulli's equation.  Of course it is also how both jet and rocket engine nozzles work.

@RobMcDonald Oh okay, thanks for pointing that out. So, last follow up question, but if you were to install an array of pressure sensors along the whole jet, how low would the lowest pressure-peak be? (As in psi or psf) Again, sorry if you’ve already answered this, and I’ve not followed.

We can't answer that using this level of theory.  At this level of abstraction, the flow is either 1) Stagnant in the reservoir or 2) in the jet.  Using Bernoulli, we could know the velocity that corresponds to any pressure between Pres and Pamb.  However, we don't have any spatial / geometric idea of how and where the flow accelerates.  Obviously, the flow must move somewhere inside the reservoir -- or else nothing would exit the orifice.  Likewise, we pay no attention to the shape of the orifice, if it is a tube, how long it is, etc.

@RobMcDonald one minor adjustment in the calcs may be that the air would cool from expansion, but would also heat exchange with the ambient air. It would probably depend on the nozzle as to what T would be when P of plume = P ambient.

@RobertDiGiovanni This calculation accounts for Tjet != Tamb, I just didn't bother making the calculation of what Tjet would be. For simplicity, I rearranged things to be in terms of quantities known up-front. If I was doing this in practice, I would have used more intermediate calculations that would have given values to other quantities along the way -- for example, rho_res=rho_jet is never calculated either. The temperature effects you're after will become much more significant as you deal with higher pressure ratios and the compressible case that necessitates the isentropic flow relations.
